# Dreamweaver CS5 code hinting

Tags: dreamweaver

I've been programming in Xcode a lot and the code hinting/autocompletion is amazing. Now Im working with CS5 and it's a pain to need to hit Crtl+Space every single time for code completion. Every time i type a letter, instead of autocompletion, dreamweaver saids "There is a syntax error on line ... Code hitting may not work until you fix this".

So is there anyway to have code hinting enable right when you type a letter or at least have error checking be less aggressive? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't get a ton of control over Dreamweaver's code hinting and syntax checking.

The code hinting can be enabled or disabled and also given a delay before appearing at Edit | Preferences | Code Hinting.

The Syntax Error in the header can be disabled in Split View or Code View from the Coding Toolbar.  Look for the icon that has the triangular yellow background with an exclamation point and toggle it.  When you have invalid syntax you'll still get red coloring on the line numbers (or left margin if you disable the line numbers) but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Go to **Edit** **Preference** (Ctrl+U) After that see the screenshot
[image: See the screenshots]