# PHP insert to MySQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dreamweaver

I'm trying to run a PHP script to insert a new record in a table of a MySQL database. It isn't working though. I opened it up in Dreamweaver and I get this message.

"There is a syntax error on line4. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error"

The code is as follows (with the connection details removed)

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("database.lcn.com","username","password","databasename");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tide_test_location (Date, Time, Sensor1Val)
VALUES ('2014-05-08', '12:15:30', '6')");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tide_test_location (Date, Time, Sensor1Val)
VALUES ('2014-04-02', '12:15:30', '4')");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This syntax is perfectly fine.

Comment: This sounds like a Dreamweaver-specific error.

Comment: See if your datatypes in your table match what youre trying to insert. Then try to run the query directly on your db, as in just copy paste "INSERT INTO tide_test_location (Date, Time, Sensor1Val)
VALUES ('2014-04-02', '12:15:30', '4')" in your db and see the specific errors, if any.

Comment: i wouldn't put `Date` and `Time` into different fields though. They should both be together in a single field of type TIMESTAMP or DATETIME.

Comment: use `echo mysqli_error($link);` to see what the error message is.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: I copied and pasted 
INSERT INTO tide_test_location (Date, Time, Sensor1Val)
VALUES ('2014-05-08', '12:15:30', '6')"

and received the error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"' at line 2"

Answer (score 0):

If your `INSERT`s are working correctly and you can see them going into the table then I would [disable code hinting in Dreamweaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764365/dreamweaver-cs5-code-hinting).

Answer (score 0):

Like deceze said before, i did not see any problem whit the sintax.

In the first place, i would recommend you using a Framework, leaving that aside i recommend you use try-catch in case the mysql fails, otherwise the app may have a catchable fatal error.

And also support de gardni comment, dreamweaver may not be the best developer tool around, but that is just IMHO.